# ¿Reproductor compatible con HTML5 y Streaming M3U8?

Tags: html, html5, video, videojs

estoy tratando de crear una aplicación web para reproducir mi contenido `.M3U8` en Streaming, pero no encuentro la forma de reproducirlo. Si utilizo HTML5 y vídeo, solamente me deja cargar `.MP4` pero no reproduce mi streaming `.M3U8` como lo pueden hacer [flowplayer](/questions/tagged/flowplayer) o [jwplayer](/questions/tagged/jwplayer). La cuestión está en si se conoce algún servicio gratuito que me permita lograr mis objetivos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tag video de HTML debería de funcionar con m3u8 si no hay bloqueo de CORS y cosas del streaming.
Sin embargo sé que puede ocasionar problemas en ocasiones específicas.

Acá te comparto un par de reproductores que uso personalmente, cada uno con sus propias virtudes.

**1. Clappr -** [Web Oficial](http://clappr.io/)

Para mi, este es el mejor y más completo reproductor por todas las opciones y plugins que te deja agregar y utilizar a tu gusto.

**2. JW Player -** [Web Oficial](https://www.jwplayer.com/)

JW es muy bonito estéticamente, pero también funcional, no tiene nada que envidiarle a Clappr.
No estoy muy seguro, pero creo que también posee PLugins y demás funcionalidades (como skins) para personalizarlo.

Te adjunto ejemplos funcionales de esos dos reproductores

Ejemplo - [Codepen Clappr](https://codepen.io/slowdmelendez360/pen/VwjXxVo)

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clappr@latest/dist/clappr.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="player"></div>
  <script>
    var player = new Clappr.Player({source: "https://5b50404ec5e4c.streamlock.net/8030/8030/chunklist.m3u8", parentId: "#player"});
  </script>
</body>
```

Ejemplo - [Codepen JW Player](https://codepen.io/slowdmelendez360/pen/xxOWjMM)

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://jwpsrv.com/library/FfMxTl3oEeSEiiIACxmInQ.js"></script>   
       <div id="aRzklaXf">Loading the player...</div>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       var playerInstance = jwplayer("aRzklaXf");
       playerInstance.setup({
        "file": "https://5b50404ec5e4c.streamlock.net/8030/8030/chunklist.m3u8",
        "height":"560",
        "width":"50%",
        stretching: "bestfit",
        "image": "#",
        "mediaid": "player",
        "mute": false,
        "autostart": false,
            "cast": {
                "appid": "player",
                "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/Tgk2YrC/Logo.png",
            },
       });
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Aidicionalmente, y como todo mundo podría dar fé, la palabra de una sola persona no es ley, es decir, para mi los anteriores pueden ser los mejores reproductores, pero para alguien más pueden ser los peores.

Hay un par de opciones más como:

Flowplayer - [Web Oficial](https://flowplayer.com/)

Bitmovin Player - [Web Oficial](https://bitmovin.com/)

DASH Js Player - [Web Oficial](https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/nightly/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html)

HLS JS Player - [Web Oficial](https://hls-js.netlify.app/demo/)

Espero que mi respuesta sea de ayuda, si tienes dudas adicionales, estaré encantado de ayudar.

Comment: Se te agradece el aporte pero he de comentarte que las preguntas basadas en opiniones o recomendaciones terminan cerrada pues no se ajustan al formato del sitio

Comment: Hola @BetaM soy nuevo en el sitio, sin embargo la pregunta tiene algún tiempo de estar publicada, por eso me decidí a responder. Gracias por la aclaración

Comment: Te comento que así pueden quedar en tanto son votadas para terminar cerradas por lo que ya te comenté

Comment: Comprendo, muchas gracias por hacérmelo saber.